# ggplot2 with clustered columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis-labels, geom-col

I am trying to plot my data and exhibit like Excel's visualization.

The testing data is below:

```
# test
yq         colA_1      colA_2    colB_1      colB_2
2014 Q1    1.072513    1.026764  0.07251283  0.026764360
2014 Q2    1.097670    1.037183  0.06731060  0.024912609
2014 Q3    1.111137    1.039893  0.06478415  0.022297469
2014 Q4    1.126760    1.042039  0.06510137  0.018822622
2015 Q1    1.143480    1.043719  0.06616912  0.016513022
2015 Q2    1.169457    1.053273  0.06539907  0.015513867
2015 Q3    1.183965    1.056728  0.06554381  0.016189236
2015 Q4    1.193858    1.059065  0.05954961  0.016339011
2016 Q1    1.201557    1.060292  0.05078975  0.015878297
2016 Q2    1.221607    1.069681  0.04459420  0.015577685
2016 Q3    1.239693    1.070330  0.04706882  0.012871887
2016 Q4    1.265686    1.069209  0.06016474  0.009578374
```

I use `ggplot2` to plot the data with line and bar graph combining them into one plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = yq)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = colA_1), colour = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = colA_2), colour = 'darkblue') +
  geom_col(aes(y = colB_1 * 5), colour = "red", fill = "white", position = "dodge") +
  geom_col(aes(y = colB_2 * 5), colour = "darkblue", fill = "lightblue", position = "dodge") +  
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Relativity",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./5, name = "YQ Growth",
                      labels = function(b) { paste0(round(b * 100, 0), "%")})) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"))
```

and here is the output. 
[image: plot1]

However, I want my plot showing like this:
[image: plot2]

In Excel, we can just use **clustered column** with different series.
[image: plot3]

How to modify my code to make my plot looks close to Excel design?

Moreover, the secondary axis looks pretty well in Excel. How to modify it? I guess R cannot automatically adjust plot's axis like Excel.

**Data:**

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(yq = structure(c(2014, 2014.25, 2014.5, 2014.75, 
2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2016, 2016.25, 2016.5, 2016.75
), class = "yearqtr"), colA_1 = c(1.07251282607859, 1.09766991723034, 
1.11113694497572, 1.126759608788, 1.14348005732242, 1.16945650644991, 
1.18396509431146, 1.19385770162439, 1.20155712357527, 1.22160748220368, 
1.23969293134377, 1.26568584199143), colA_2 = c(1.02676435956276, 
1.03718273614132, 1.03989293246398, 1.04203868693514, 1.04371934229503, 
1.05327345142754, 1.0567280041501, 1.05906456813454, 1.06029182761268, 
1.06968101384557, 1.07033008728214, 1.06920868464074), colB_1 = c(0.0725128260785901, 
0.0673106045814515, 0.0647841488910708, 0.0651013729757453, 0.0661691212619855, 
0.0653990676912228, 0.0655438104772257, 0.059549607842762, 0.0507897500100214, 
0.0445941986436791, 0.0470688175690868, 0.0601647418024032), 
colB_2 = c(0.0267643595627607, 0.0249126094335301, 0.0222974693061362, 
0.0188226218410159, 0.0165130222668561, 0.0155138672535979, 
0.0161892356035436, 0.0163390106460137, 0.0158782966321198, 
0.0155776853539686, 0.0128718866904485, 0.00957837398344408
)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002254bd91ef0>)

test <- fread("yq   colA_1  colA_2  colB_1  colB_2
2014 Q1 1.072513    1.026764    0.07251283  0.02676436
2014 Q2 1.09767 1.037183    0.0673106   0.024912609
2014 Q3 1.111137    1.039893    0.06478415  0.022297469
2014 Q4 1.12676 1.042039    0.06510137  0.018822622
2015 Q1 1.14348 1.043719    0.06616912  0.016513022
2015 Q2 1.169457    1.053273    0.06539907  0.015513867
2015 Q3 1.183965    1.056728    0.06554381  0.016189236
2015 Q4 1.193858    1.059065    0.05954961  0.016339011
2016 Q1 1.201557    1.060292    0.05078975  0.015878297
2016 Q2 1.221607    1.069681    0.0445942   0.015577685
2016 Q3 1.239693    1.07033 0.04706882  0.012871887
2016 Q4 1.265686    1.069209    0.06016474  0.009578374
", header = T)
test$yq <- as.yearqtr(test$yq)
```

Comment: Hi, could you share your data set using `dput()`?
because library `overflow::soread` is not able to read the correct structure of your data.

Comment: I updated it. Is that what you want?

Comment: There is something strange in your data set, are you sure you have well copied the data? `structure(list(yq = structure(c(2014,[...]`

Comment: I added another one with `data.table::fread()`.

Comment: I am really sorry, but using the output of your `dput()` doesn't work. Using the output of `fread` it doesn't recognize the header (dim 11 * 6) with two variables year and quarterly separated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. Most likely, there are different ways to achieve the goal. Here, is what I would do.

First reshape the data from wide to long format, extract the grouping parameters `A`, `B` and `1`, `2`, resp. Then call `ggplot()` with appropriate scales for colour and fill:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

long <- melt(setDT(test), id.vars = "yq")[
  , grp1 := stringr::str_sub(variable, 4, 4)][
    , grp2 := stringr::str_sub(variable, 6, 6)][]

ggplot(data = long, aes(x = yq, y = value, colour = grp2, fill = grp2)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = 10 * value), data = long[grp1 == "B"], position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(data = long[grp1 == "A"]) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "darkblue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "lightblue")) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Relativity",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name = "YQ Growth",
                                         labels = scales::percent)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "darkblue"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

#### EDIT: Add labels to the bars

[In a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258482/ggplot2-with-clustered-columns/56259879#comment99141033_56259879), the OP has asked to "add the percent numbers one each bar".

It is possible but requires some experimentation with the `width` parameter passed to of the different calls of `position_dodge()`:

```
sec_axis_mult <- 10
ggplot(data = long, aes(x = yq, y = value, colour = grp2, fill = grp2, 
                        label = scales::percent(value, accuracy = 0.1))) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = sec_axis_mult * value), data = long[grp1 == "B"], 
           position = position_dodge2(width = 0)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = sec_axis_mult * value), data = long[grp1 == "B"], 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.25),
            vjust = -0.3, size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = long[grp1 == "A"]) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "darkblue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "lightblue")) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Relativity",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./sec_axis_mult, name = "YQ Growth",
                                         labels = scales::percent)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "darkblue"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Can I possible to add the percent numbers one each bar?

Comment: What is the `sec_axis_mult` in `geom_col`?

Comment: @PeterChen, this is a "named constant" which is used in three different places (in the calls to `geom_col()`, `geom_text()`, and `sec_axis()`). I have defined it in one place as `sec_axis_mult <- 10` so it can be changed easily.

Comment: Although the plot seems correct, there is a little thing on x-axis. Is it possible to show all quarters on the x-axis?

Comment: Yes, use `scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", breaks = unique(long$yq))`